# Pivot table in python pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot

i want to create a pivot table in pandas and showing the name of the country, Year, and value of that year, this is how it looks the table :
[image]

How can i use pivot to turn the name of columns into Country Name, Year, and Value

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problem :

```
data = data.melt(id_vars=['Country Name','Indicator Name'],  var_name='Year').sort_values('Country Name')
```